# How to compute the Gaussian measure of a ball centered at the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

The Gaussian measure is the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with density
$$\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}.$$

The ball is defined as
$$B_r = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: \|x\| \le r\}.$$

How to compute
$$\mathbb{P}(B_r) = \int_{x\in B_r}\frac{e^{-\|x\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}dx?$$

Comment: What have you tried? Spherical coordinates lead to an evaluation in terms of the incomplete gamma function. ($r^2$ is chi-squared distributed.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I have no idea how to solve this. Could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand is radially symmetric so we can use spherical coordinates and not have to worry about the angular coordinates. $d^dx\propto \rho^{d-1}d\rho,$ so $$ P(B_r) \propto\int_0^re^{-\rho^2/2}\rho^{d-1}d\rho \propto\int_0^{r^2/2} e^{-u}u^{d/2-1}du = \gamma(d/2,r^2/2)$$ where $\gamma$ is the lower incomplete Gamma function. The proportionality constant can be found by normalization.